# How to use iconutil on mac to generate icns file

Tags: qt, iconutil

I have created a directory with the icon set extension and put some png file there.  After typing the below commands I have been unable to generating icon files.

```
$ mkdir myicon.iconset
$ iconutil -c icns myicon.iconset
$ Failed to generate ICNS.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually create icns files using iconutil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306223/how-to-manually-create-icns-files-using-iconutil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files inside of myicon.iconset need to have a particular naming structure, e.g.:

icon.iconset/icon_128x128.png
icon.iconset/icon_128x128@2x.png
icon.iconset/icon_256x256.png
icon.iconset/icon_256x256@2x.png