# How to customize and test executable path, main icon, and i18n of a MacOS .app bundle

Tags: macos, plist, bundle

I have a MacOS app bundle bare bones working. That is, it runs the executable, that's it. Icon still isn't working even though I have an `MyApp.icns` file I can visually see in Finder. And i18n isn't working.

```
MyApp.app/
  Contents/
    Info.plist
    MacOS/
      MyApp # executable
    Resources/
      MyApp.icns
      en.lproj
        InfoPlist.strings
      jp.lproj
        InfoPlist.strings
```

The `.icns` I generated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306223/how-to-manually-create-icns-files-using-iconutil/20703594#20703594):

```
mkdir MyIcon.iconset
sips -z 16 16     foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_16x16.png
sips -z 32 32     foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_16x16@2x.png
sips -z 32 32     foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_32x32.png
sips -z 64 64     foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_32x32@2x.png
sips -z 128 128   foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_128x128.png
sips -z 256 256   foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_128x128@2x.png
sips -z 256 256   foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_256x256.png
sips -z 512 512   foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_256x256@2x.png
sips -z 512 512   foo.png --out MyIcon.iconset/icon_512x512.png
cp Icon1024.png MyIcon.iconset/icon_512x512@2x.png
iconutil -c icns MyIcon.iconset
rm -R MyIcon.iconset
```

My Info.plist is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>

  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>

  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>

  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>

  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0.0</string>

  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>APPL</string>

  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>

  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>this/has/no/effect</string>

  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>NeitherDoesThis</string>
</dict>
```

The InfoPlist.strings for each language looks like this:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Foo";
NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright © 2019 Me.";
```

or:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "ふ";
NSHumanReadableCopyright = "著作権法 © 2019 目.";
```

The problems I'm having are:

- I can't specify the executable path, it only works if it is named the same as `MyApp.app`, so `MyApp` executable.
- The icon `MyApp.icns` isn't rendering in the /Applications folder (which is the only place I've put it so far). I'm not sure if I can customize that path either.
- I'm not sure how to test if i18n works.

Wondering if one could verify that stuff, and show how to test the other things. Specifically:

1. Verify that you can't actually customize the path of the executable, it *must* be named the same as the app in the MacOS folder.
2. Verify that you must name the icon the same as the app, with .icns extension. I'm not sure this is true because for example Skypes main Icon is in the Resources/Skype Blue.icns location, and they say `Skype Blue` in the Info.plist. Wondering why I can't get this working.
3. How to test that i18n works. Wondering if I just [change the Mac system language](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=43834) and open the app again, etc.

This is all without using XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Info.plist` missing/incorrect keys/strings can affect the first two concerns; if keys are duplicated, missing, or set incorrectly it can certainly cause issues with functionality.

1. **Missing**

   - `NSPrincipalClass`
   - `CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion`
   - `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms`
   - `CFBundlePackageType`
   - `CFBundleExecutable` (this is the binary inside MacOS folder)
   - `CFBundleLocalizations` (optional)
   - `DTXcode` (optional)
   - `DTPlatform` (optional)
   - `DTSDK` (optional)
   - `DTCompiler` (optional)
2. **Incorrect**

   - `CFBundleIdentifier` (should be in reverse DNS format)
   - `CFBundleVersion` (duplicate/incorrect)
   - `CFBundleSignature` (incorrect)

**NOTES**: The application name `MyApp.app` does not need to be the same as the executable file inside the `MacOS` folder as long as you've added and set the key `CFBundleExecutable`. The application icon can be any name you want as well, the key to having it work is by including the additional `CoreFoundation` keys shown above set correctly.

Once you've got all the missing/incorrect keys sorted you should end up with something similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>MyIcon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>10B61</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>18B71</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.14</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>1010</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>10B61</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.13</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2019 MyApp. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

<sub>*The `Info.plist` above should work with your app, as the values are set to what you've shown in your question.</sub>

---

Regarding `i18n` testing — the [`Internationalization and Localization Guide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH1-SW1) the sections [`Testing Your Internationalized App`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW1) and [`Managing Strings Files Yourself`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH19-SW22) should be helpful. There's a huge amount of information within the Guide; a one size fits all approach to testing usually won't do so you'll want to find what works best for you.

> → [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009248-SW1)
>  → [About
>   Internationalization and Localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Thank you so much. Wondering if `NSMainNibFile` is required. I am not using XCode.

Comment: You’re welcome! If your app doesn’t have windows then it’s not necessary. The information mentioned at the following link highlights the recommended keys: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW4